# Text boxes appended by JS squish together unexpectedly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, view

I have a group of text input boxes created in my html like so:

```
<div id='inputs'>
    <% 6.times do |i| %>

        <%= text_field_tag "box_" + i.to_s, nil, { :id => "box_" + i.to_s,
        :class => "boxes"} %>

    <% end %>
</div>
```

I then have a JS listener for a button below the boxes:

```
var nextId = 6;

$("#addBtn").on("click",function(){
    $("#inputs").append("<input type='text' class='boxes' id='box_"+nextCCId+"'/>");
    nextId++;
});
```

The problem is this:[image]

Text boxes added when rendering are spaced out, but boxes added with JS don't space.

The styling of the two types of boxes appears to be exactly the same on my browsers element inspector, what's going on?  It appeared to work properly before.  I'm not sure if I just now noticed or I did something to cause this, but undoing my recent changes does not fix it.  Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you're simply missing a space in your jquery markup.

```
$("#addBtn").on("click",function(){
    $("#inputs").append("<input type='text' class='boxes' id='box_"+nextCCId+"'/> <!-- space added here -->");
    nextId++;
});
```

Comment: Thank you!  That's an interesting quirk of html I was not aware of.